# Converting IsClosedTypeOf from autofac to simple.injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am following the [CQS posts by .net junkie](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) and have implemented a `QueryProcessor`. In this post he quotes:-

> Using the IQueryProcessor means we have to write a test that confirms
>   there is a corresponding query handler for every query in the system,
>   because the DI framework can not check this for you.

In the comments of this post someone has created a test using [autofac](/questions/tagged/autofac) that uses an extension method `IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IQuery<>))` I would like to use [simple-injector](/questions/tagged/simple-injector)

However I am struggling to work out how to convert/create an extension method `IsClosedTypeOf` for use without using auto-fac?

```
    var allQueryTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IQuery<>)).GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IQuery<>)))
            .ToList();
```

I am not even 100% sure what `IsClosedTypeOf` does as I am not familiar with autofac

Source of [test code](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/12/test-all-you-query-to-have-queryhandler/).

Comment: We once considered adding a public `IsClosedTypeOf` extension method to Simple Injector, but in the end decided not to. It's a useful extension method, but this would pollute the Simple Injector API. This is such a general construct, this extension method is more something that should be added to the .NET BCL itself, not to your DI container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
var allQueryTypes =
    from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from type in assembly.GetTypes()
    where !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    let queryInterfaces =
        from iface in type.GetInterfaces()
        where iface.IsGenericType
        where iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQuery<>)
        select iface
    where queryInterfaces.Any()
    select type;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Nice blog btw. Really like the way you craft your software.